# Test for stationarity

Tags: r, time-series, stationarity

I need to check second order stationarity of a time series of length 7320 (I have 1800 such time series). These time series are displacement recorded at 1800 sites on a mountain. I tried using Priestley-Subba Rao in R : `stationarity()`. For 1 time series out of 1800, I got these values:

> p-value for T : 2.109424e-15
>
> p-value for I+R : 9.447661e-06
>
> p-value for T+I+R : 1.4099e-10

Could you please tell me how to interpret it. All I know is if the p-value for T is 0, the null hypothesis of time series being stationary is rejected. Also, for 2nd time series out of 1800, I got these values;

> p-value for T : 0
>
> p-value for I+R : 1.458063e-09
>
> p-value for T+I+R : 0

Could you tell me how to differentiate between the two. Both the time series are from the same dataset. Also, is it possible that one time series is stationary and another is not, given the fact they are from the same site and recorded at the exact same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this article](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~magpn/Research/LSTS/TOS.html), you can decide on the second order stationarity based on `p-value T`. Although the article only mentions that "*In this example the p-value is essentially zero which indicates that there is very strong evidence to reject the null hypothesis of stationarity.*", you can apply the general hypothesis test decision rule:

$$p\text{-value} < \text{significance level} \Rightarrow \text{reject } H_0 \text{, accept } H_1$$

If you have no idea what significance level to use, use one of the regular values: 5%, 1% and 0,1% (the less the significance level, the stronger the evidence against $H_0$).

So as in the first case $p\text{-value} = 2.109424e-15$ (virtually $0$) and in the second case $p\text{-value} = 0$, the decision is the same: reject $H_0$, what means you can reject second order stationarity on every sane significance levels (i.e. there is no difference in the stationarity of the time series).